# Setting flow variables in MUnit with java

Tags: java, mule, anypoint-studio, munit

I am implementing MUnit with java for a mule flow. The flow is having a flow variable who's value is being derived from a variable in another flow. So, I need to have this value set in java which would be run as Junit.

Please let me know how do we set flow/session variables in Java that will be testing the mule flow.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set variables on test message. Check this post - https://unittesters.com/blog/mule-munit-testing-variables-properties/

Comment: Works !!
Thanks for it !

Comment: Also, is there any way to pick up data from a file and set it in a flow variable in java which would be run as junit

Comment: you can use this MEL to read file `<set-variable variableName='mydata' value=#[getResource('filepath').asString()]/>`

Answer (score 0):

We can set it by using eventcontext as below:

eventContext.getMessage().setInvocationProperty(key, value);

So , you can access that flow variable by key anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
    <set-session-variable doc:name="Session Variable" value="#[flowVars.acme_id]" variableName="myVar"/>
    <set-variable variableName="munit-json-payload" value="#[getResource('testData/good-response.json').asString()]" doc:name="Variable"/>
```